# How do I get Ordnance?

Tags: halo-4

I have noticed that I sometimes get access to an "Ordnance Drop" similar to killstreak rewards in the Call of Duty series.  I know that I am getting it for doing things, but I'd like to know how many of those things I need to do in order to get a drop.  Also, is ordnance available in all game types?  If not, in which is it available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personal Ordnance drops are obtained in Infinity Slayer and Big Team Infinity Slayer.

[As 343 explains it](http://www.neoseeker.com/news/19774-halo-4-multiplayers-new-infinity-slayer-ordnance-drops-explained/):

> As you earn medals, you fill up your ordnance meter. When that meter is full, you earn a reward drop for yourself from the Infinity. The reward comes in the form of three randomized power weapons, grenades, or powerups (two of the former, one of the latter). You can then choose which one you want, and the Infinity will drop the ordnance (if you’re inside, it will teleport in). You won’t get the highest tier power weapons (e.g., rockets) in personal ordnance, but everything you do get is powerfully awesome. And awesomely powerful. And everything in between.

The key part being **"As you earn medals"**. Therefore the ordnance meter fills faster for doing more 'stylized' kills, such as Multi Kills, Assassinations, Retributions, Reload This, and the many more medals.

For an example:
If you throw a plasma grenade that sticks to an opponent who was reloading, then quickly assassinate another opponent, all while being shot at and then your team-mate kills the opponent shooting at you, that would net you **5** medals (Plasma Kill, Reload This, Assassination, Double Kill, Distraction) and significantly increase your ordnance meter.

Also a note from my own experience, you cannot receive an ordnance drop while in a vehicle.  The meter still increases for what you do in said vehicle, but it will not show you how full the meter is nor will it inform you if it is full until you jump out of the vehicle, or you die.  If you happen to die in the vehicle, or whenever you achieve an ordnance drop, you will retain the earned drop and be able to call it in when you next spawn.

Check out [tombull89's answer below](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/94546/21619) if you want to see point totals required for each drop.

Comment: I'd like to see the point total requirements, and then I will accept.  From custom games, I see the default is 70 pts with a 30% increase each time you get ordnance.  It should be verified in matchmaking.  I'll do it when I get a chance, but if you beat me to it please update your answer.

Comment: @EBongo Well I won't be able to do it till later tonight.  Which ever of use find it first can simply add it in :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you get ordnance drops from getting a certain number of points. So, when you get a message on the screen that says that you get points, the ordnance drop.

Ordnance drops are not available in all game types. The only  game types (or at least playlists) that you can get ordnance drop in are Infinity Slayer and Big Team Infinity Slayer.

Answer (score 1):

After playing a couple of games of Big Team Invasion Slayer, I've found it takes me 70 points to get my first ordnance drop, and then 90 or 95 points to get the second. I would say the next drop after that is 125 but I haven't managed to do well enough to get three drops in one game. The Halo 4 Strategy Guide has a list of all the medals and their points value for further reading.

Comment: Do you happen to have the count?  I've compiled my own list, and I believe it is the most complete list there is.  I have 160...

Comment: Heh... make that 161.

Comment: I just took some measurements in a custom game, and I got Ordinance at 70, then at 105, then at 120.  Probably some rounding error there, so it looks like our results match.  +1 for research.

Comment: @EBongo, a list of all the medals and their points value? It's quite an extensive list, covering about 4 pages in the book.

Comment: Okay. In the online Prima Guide, War Games section [here](http://www.primagames.com/games/halo-4/primaguides/382/multiplayer/16404?sn=4.1) the medal table is the first at the top. Also note how some medals may count towards your score but less towards any ordnance drops. For example, a Hail Mary grenade throw counts +10 for score but only +5 for ordnance meter.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see the table you are referring to, likely because I haven't bought the guide.

Comment: @EBongo, I did wonder about that. There's some medals listed on the Wikis but not the points value. Don't know what to suggest apart from buying one of the guides.